# Yii application setup/installation like wordpress installation

Tags: yii, installation, yii-extensions

I am looking for an extension that I can use to setup the settings for a Yii application.
The extension would be like the wordpress installation where you have the UI to input the application name, the database settings, smtp configurations, document root and initial user settings.
Is there an available extension like that on Yii?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing out there is a tool called Phundanent, but the short answer is no. Yii is aimed more at programmers, who in turn will be handling that type of thing themselves ...